# Control color of edges in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, color, mesh

I have a list of 2D points I want to plot with `ListPlot`. I want the edges connecting these points to have certain colors. So in addition to setting the `ListPlot` option `Joined` to `True`, I will also need to set the `Mesh` and `MeshShading` options. As far as I know, the only value for the `Mesh` option that will put a mesh point at each point I pass to `ListPlot` is [`Mesh->Full`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html). However, if I use this value, then the `MeshShading` option doesn't seem to do anything.

To get a minimum working example, I will just go to the `ListPlot` [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) and go to Options and then MeshShading in their drill-down menu.

The first example is

```
ListPlot[Table[Binomial[15, k], {k, 0, 15}], Mesh -> 10, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> True]
```

which produces

[image]

But, as I explained, I will have to use `Mesh->Full`, so I make this change to the command to get the following command

```
ListPlot[Table[Binomial[15, k], {k, 0, 15}], Mesh -> Full, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> True]
```

The command produces the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, the mesh does not have the specified coloring. My question is, "How do I get `ListPlot` to use the given value of the `MeshShading` option when I am also using the option `Mesh->Full`?"

Notice that I realize

```
ListPlot[Table[Binomial[15, k], {k, 0, 15}], Mesh -> {Range[16], {}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> True]
```

(for example), gives me what I want in this case, but in general, I will be plotting an arbitrary list of 2D points, so this will not work.

Comment: Would the alternative `Mesh -> Length[points]`, where `points` is your arbitrary list of 2D points, work? More explicitly, once the list `points` is generated, something like: `With[{p = points}, ListPlot[p, Mesh -> Length[p], MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> True]]`.

Comment: @Xavier No that creates meshpoints wherever the x coordinate on an edge has one of `Length[points]` evenly spaced values. Try it. `ListPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {12, 2}], Mesh -> 12, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> True]`

Comment: Good point, I just tried it. I can think of a workaround with `Show`, `Graphics` (to draw colored lines) and `ListPlot` (for the points), but this seems a little ugly (and as a workaround, it does not answer your question).

Comment: So why can't you take the x coordinates from your arbitrary list and put them into `Mesh`?

Comment: @C. E. I don't understand. You mean like this? `data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {12, 2}];
ListPlot[data, Mesh -> {data[[;; , 1]], {}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> True]`

Comment: Alright, with that kind of list it isn't possible to do what you want with just the mesh options, I believe, and as Xavier believes. If you ask for any workaround I'm sure people will be happy to supply solutions using `Graphics` and perhaps rule replacements on the `ListPlot` output, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of subtleties here that are not captured by your minimal working example but are obvious from the comments discussion: you have a non-uniformly sampled dataset you want to plot as opposed to the uniformly sampled one `uniData = Table[Binomial[15, k], {k, 0, 15}]`. If you had a uniformly sampled dataset, the solution suggested by @Xavier in the comments `Mesh-> Length@uniData` is fine as far as I can see.

But a non-uniform dataset, like:

```
nonuniData = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {12, 2}];
```

you want a parameter along the curve as a mesh function and `#3` is exaclty that. So

```
ListLinePlot[nonuniData,
 MeshFunctions -> {-#3 &}, 
 Mesh -> (Length@nonuniData - 1), 
 MeshShading -> {Blue, Red}]
```

produces the desired (although the first point is missing so you'd have to add this manually).

[image]

This doesn't include the option `Mesh->Full` however.

Comment: Thanks for this answer it seems useful. Where did you learn about using `#3` for `MeshFunctions` with `ListPlot`? If you go to the [`MeshFunctions` page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) and click on details, and go to their fourth bullet point, it says in the first row of the table of this bullet point that `ListLinePlot` mesh functions are given only two arguments, which are x and y. (I see `ParametricPlot` gets a third argument though.) Also, can you comment on why the minus sign in front of #3 is necessary?

Comment: And as far as the missing point, I am lucky that in my case, the points are supposed to lie on a closed curve, so I am really passing `Append[data,First@data]` to `ListPlot`, so all my points will get drawn. Of course, a simple workaround in the original case would be `Prepend[data,First@data]`, and then make sure to change the number of mesh points from `Length@data-1` to `Length@data` to take into account the extra data point you are passing to `ListPlot`.

Comment: I am trying to remember where I first saw that `#3` can be used as an argument in `MeshFunctions` but I can't. It's entirely possible I was  stuck with something similar - for the record, I have also used `ArcLength` as a Mesh function. I didn't know that was an option either...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround suggested by Xavier in the comments. First make some dummy data:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {12, 2}];
```

now make some dummy colors for the data:

```
colors = Hue /@ (Range@Length@data/Length@data)
```

then to make my plot, I can do

```
Show[{
  ListPlot[data],
  Graphics[MapThread[{#3, Line[{#1, #2}]} &,{data,RotateLeft@data,colors}]]
}]
```

Basically, I am using `ListPlot` to plot the points, and then just making the lines myself. I would hope there is a better answer though.